# pthread running an event loop never continues execution

Tags: c, pthreads

I'm attempting to run an event loop from within a pthread but I've run into a problem I can't seem to google-fix. Basically, it looks like this:

```
event_thread = pthread_create(&event_thread, NULL, 
  (void *) g_main_loop_run, (void *) event_loop);

printf("GOT HERE\n");
```

The message below pthread_create never prints, is there a way to "fire and forget" a thread?

Comment: That's what threads are supposed to do! Can you give us more detail? Maybe some more of the code which surrounds those calls, and a description of your environment (OS, compiler, versions etc.)?

Comment: To start with, `pthread_create()` returns a number indicating success or failure -- don't assign its return to `event_thread`.

Comment: good catch, luckily just a brain failure on my part when typing the question out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, figured that one out as soon as I posted this, here's what I ended up doing:

```
pthread_attr_t attr;
...
pthread_attr_init(&thread_attr);
pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&thread_attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
event_thread = pthread_create(&event_thread, &thread_attr, 
    (void *) g_main_loop_run, (void *) event_loop);
```

You just need to set the threads state to "detached".

Comment: Even without creating it detached, the main thread should have continued past the call to `pthread_create()`

Comment: That will have no effect on the problem you mentioned. Your original problem was caused by something else.

Comment: well that's sure strange, everything appears to be working as expected now.